# Should deletion of users also delete questions with accepted and upvoted answers?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

It isn't very encouraging when a community bot deletes the question having an upvoted and accepted answer when the question author is deleted. I think it should be left to the humans and the bot should only be able to delete unanswered questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72841625/while-loop-will-not-become-false-in-c/72841657#72841657

Comment: So Community deleted that post in conjunction with the deletion of the User. This was not part of the standard [roomba removal](/help/roomba), so a human _was_ involved here.

Comment: Why do you think it should not be removed?

Comment: the question has a lot of code but no error message or other indication  what is wrong and is rightfully closed nobody can find is as long it has not the exact same code, what is unlikely so it will never help anybody else.

Comment: In the future, when you come across this question, please vote/flag to close it as a duplicate of the canonical https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003. It's language agnostic, so it can be used for programming questions in any language where the underlying issue is the misapplication of de Morgan's law in this way.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post into complete "feature-request"? It is quite unclear why you think "preserve non-upvoted content on account deletion" is a good option for the site.

Comment: Not everything should be encouraged. Some things should be discouraged.

Comment: @cigien I don't think "language agnostic" vague posts are particularly helpful. De Morgan's laws are pretty much prerequisite knowledge for programming, so there is no need to explain them here... doing so would make it an off-topic math answer. Besides, most people can apply common sense regardless if they know De Morgan's or not: "if the sheep is not white or the sheep is not black" ought to say "_and_". Just point out the logic flaw in a comment and close as simple typo. These kind of questions are common enough and very uninteresting, it's nothing we need to keep or answer.

Comment: @Lundin There's nothing remotely vague about that question. It's an extremely specific question about a kind of logic error in programming that comes up very often, and it's useful to have a target for that very reason. Yes, it's a simple enough error that's easy to solve, but that's not a reason to close it as "typo". I do agree that these questions don't need to be answered, but that's only because a target already exists. Also, please use the target to help the OP, rather than leaving a comment saying the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it should. As long as the question is closed, if its author is gone, there's little chance anyone else would be able to improve the question. Closing means that we expect the author to provide more information or clarification, and if they are gone who is going to make the question answerable?

In this case, the question wasn't good. Its author decided to delete their account for some reason. The answer was ok, but it's nothing special that we need to preserve. I am pretty sure there are similar answers available on the site already. We haven't lost anything. You, as an answerer, might have lost a few minutes of your time, but it's only a lesson for the future to be pickier with the questions you answer.

However, if the question was wrongly closed or if it can be edited and reopened, you can flag for the moderator's attention and ask to undelete. But the question would have to be reopened first and be in a good overall state for a mod to consider undeleting it.